# Node.js async callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm attempting to create a final array with data pulled from 3 functions. The first two functions have all the data but then the 3rd function needs to run looping through one of the fields from function 2 in order to have the complete array at the end.

I'm looking for some advice and examples on how to fix this and or do it better.  I have been advised promises would be a good solution, but could someone throw together a quick example so I can better get my head around it?

1. In my services controller I have this as the page [here](http://domain.com/services/all) and checks if the user is logged in.

   ```
   exports.all = function(req, res){
       if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
           res.redirect('login');
       } else {
   ```
2. It uses the services database schema in the model to connect to the database and pull out the info I need:

   ```
   Database
       .find()
       .exec(function (err, services) {
         if (err) {
           return console.log(err);
         }
         if (!services) {
           console.log('Failed to load any Services');
         }
   ```
3. Once the services are found (multiple RPC/API services that have the same commands but different data returned), I async through each and connect.

   ```
               async.mapSeries(services, function(service, cb) {
                   connect(service);
                   client.getBalance(req.user._id, 6, function(err, balance) {
                       console.log(balance);
                       if (err) balance = "Offline";
                       client.getAddressesByAccount(req.user._id, function(err, address) {
                           console.log(address);
                           if (err) address = "Offline";
   ```
4. Once the first two lots of data is returned (the first is just a string number and the second is an array of addresses then for each address I want too async again and run a third command and then map the result of each to the corresponding address from above and output a final array to pass to the view.

   ```
                           if(address != "Offline") {
                               async.mapSeries(address, function (item, callback){ 
                               // print the key
                               client.cmd('getreceivedbyaddress', item, 6, function(err, addressrecevied) {
                                   if (err) console.log(err);
                                       console.log(item + " = " + addressrecevied);
                                       // console.log(JSON.stringify(addressrecevied, null, 4));
                                   });
                               callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
                               }, function(err) {
                                   console.log('iterating done');
                               });
                           };



                           // console.log(service.abr + " address = " + address);
                           console.log(service.abr + " balance = " + balance);
   ```
5. Callback that outputs the current top two results to the view variables:

   ```
                           return cb(null, {
                                   name: service.name,
                                   display: service.display,
                                   address: address,
                                   balance: balance,
                                   abr: service.abr,
                           });
                       });
                   });
   ```
6. Function to call the view and pass variables when done:

   ```
               }, function(err, services) {
                       // console.log(services);
                       if (err) {
                               return console.log(err);
                       }

                   req.breadcrumbs('Services', '/services/all');
                       res.render('services/index', {
                               title: 'Services',
                               icon: 'iconfa-cog',
                               summary: 'Services information',
                               services: services,
                               path : req.path,
                               breadcrumbs: req.breadcrumbs(),
                               udata : req.session.user
                       });
                   });
           });
       }
   }
   ```

**Work in progress**

```
exports.all = function(req, res){
if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('login');
} else {
    Wallet
    .find()
    .exec(function (err, wallets) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (!wallets) {
        console.log('Failed to load any Wallets');
      }
      async.mapSeries(wallets, function(coin, cb) {

                //
                // Q FUNCTION START
                //

                function getServiceBalance(service) {
                  connect(service);
                  cmd = Q.denodeify(client.cmd.bind(client)),
                getBalance = Q.denodeify(client.getBalance.bind(client)),
                getAddressesByAccount = Q.denodeify(client.getAddressesByAccount.bind(client));

                  client.getBalance(req.user._id, 6, function(err, balance) {
                        console.log("Service: " + service.name + " - Balance: " + balance);
                        if (err) balance = "Offline";
                    });

                  // We're going to fill this in step by step...
                  var result = {
                    name: service.name,
                    display: service.display,
                    abr: service.abr
                  };

                  return getBalance(req.user._id, 6)
                    .then(function (balance) {
                      result.balance = balance;
                      console.log("Balance:" + balance);
                      console.log("User ID: " + req.user._id);
                      return getAddressesByAccount(req.user._id);
                    })
                    .then(function (addresses) {
                      result.address = addresses;
                      console.log("Addresses:" + result.address);

                      if (!_.isArray(addresses)) {
                        // Throwing errors inside `then` is fine: they will get caught in `catch` below
                        throw new Error('Could not get addresses array');
                      }

                      // For each address, call getreceivedbyaddress and gather results in array
                      return Q.all(_.map(addresses, function (address) {
                        return cmd('getreceivedbyaddress', address, 6);
                      }));
                    }).then(function (addressesReceived) {
                      result.addressReceived = addressesReceived;
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                      // Here's the catch method--the *one and only* place all errors propagate to.
                      console.log(err);

                      result.balance = 'Offline';
                      result.address = 'Offline';
                      result.addressReceived = 'Offline';
                    }).thenResolve(result);
                }


                exec().then(function (services) {
                  if (!services) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to load any Services');
                  }

                  return Q.all(_.map(services, getServiceBalance), function (serviceBalances) {
                    req.breadcrumbs('Services', '/services/all');
                      res.render('services/index', {
                        title: 'Services',
                        icon: 'iconfa-cog',
                        summary: 'Services information',
                        services: serviceBalances,
                        path : req.path,
                        breadcrumbs: req.breadcrumbs(),
                        udata : req.session.user
                      });
                    });
                  }).done();

                //
                // Q FUNCTION END
                //

            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered ditching async/callbacks for promises, e.g. with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)? Edit: Sorry, I haven't noticed you already said that.

Comment: Just wrote you an example. Let me know if something ain't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Q promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) it would look more or less like this (taking [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12303/discussion-between-dan-abramov-and-medoix) into account):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') 
, Q = require('q')
, Wallet = mongoose.model('Wallet')
, _ = require('underscore')
, bitcoin = require('bitcoin');

function connect(coin) { 
  return new bitcoin.Client({ 
    host: coin.host, 
    port: coin.port, 
    user: coin.user, 
    pass: coin.pass, 
  }); 
}

var wallet = Wallet.find(),
    exec = Q.denodeify(wallet.exec.bind(wallet));

function getServiceBalance(service, userID) {
  var client = connect(service)
  , cmd = Q.denodeify(client.cmd.bind(client))
  , getBalance = Q.denodeify(client.getBalance.bind(client))
  , getAddressesByAccount = Q.denodeify(client.getAddressesByAccount.bind(client));

  // We're going to fill this in step by step...
  var result = {
    name: service.name,
    display: service.display,
    abr: service.abr
  };

  return getBalance(userID, 6)
    .then(function (balance) {
      result.balance = balance;
      console.log("Balance:" + balance);
      console.log("User ID: " + userID);
      return getAddressesByAccount(userID);
    })
    .then(function (addresses) {
      console.log("Addresses:", address);

      if (!_.isArray(addresses)) {
        // Throwing errors inside `then` is fine: they will get caught in `catch` below
        throw new Error('Could not get addresses array');
      }

      // For each address, call getreceivedbyaddress and gather results in array
      return Q.all(_.map(addresses, function (address) {
        return cmd('getreceivedbyaddress', address, 6).then(function (received) {
          return [address, received];
        });
      }));
    }).then(function (addressesReceived) {
      result.address = _.object(addressesReceived);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      // Here's the catch method--the *one and only* place all errors propagate to.
      console.log(err);

      result.balance = 'Offline';
      result.address = 'Offline';
    }).thenResolve(result);
}

exports.all = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
      res.redirect('login');
  } else {
    exec().then(function (services) {
      if (!services) {
        throw new Error('Failed to load any Services');
      }

      var promises = _.map(services, function (service) {
          return getServiceBalance(service, req.user._id);
      });

      return Q.all(promises);
    }).then(function (serviceBalances) {
      req.breadcrumbs('Services', '/services/all');
      res.render('services/index', {
        title: 'Services',
        icon: 'iconfa-cog',
        summary: 'Services information',
        services: serviceBalances,
        path : req.path,
        breadcrumbs: req.breadcrumbs(),
        udata : req.session.user
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Error:', err);
      // TODO: render an error message?
    }).done();
  }
}
```

Note that we could've gone side-effect-free and remove captured `result` variable from `getServiceBalance` but I don't think it's worth the hassle, and in fact debugging with state is more convenient, as long as the state is properly isolated.

If you're looking to Q-style alternative to `mapSeries`, check out [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) and [`Q.allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled).

Comment: Thanks Dan! I take it this is just a function and i will still need the top part of my page function to find the services and use async to go through each and run this function you have created? the getreceivedbyaddress in the code os the third function i could not get working and basically i need to run that command for each address returned in the previous function (returned in an array) and then add the result as a sub item in the array to the address above.

Comment: @medoix I've extracted some code in `getServiceBalance` but my code should be equivalent to yours (I'm also calling `exec` and “gathering” results into a single array below by virtue of `Q.all`). See code below `getServiceBalance`, on the very bottom.

Comment: @medoix Do you need to gather an array of results of calling `getreceivedbyaddress` for each item in `address` and then put it into `service` (my `result`)?

Comment: @medoix So `getAddressesByAccount` may return an `"Offline"` string *or* an array? That's a bad design.

Comment: @medoix I fixed the code to call `getreceivedbyaddress` for each item in `addresses` (I think naming it `address` is misleading if this is an array...)

Comment: 1. getServiceBalance returns a single value for each service (i believe it is a string.) eg. "5.0001"  2. getAddressesByAccount returns an array of addresses from each service as above (array) eg. ['fdkngkngdsgnlsdg', 'fdsfdsfdsfsds', 'dsfdsfdsfsdfs']  3. getReceivedByAddress returns a single value as the first and needs to be run against each address from step 2 above. eg. "6.00002"  4. A new array needs to be created and past to the view that has the balance, the addresses and the balance of each address.

Comment: @medoix: If I'm not mistaken, this is exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: awesome, i have it compiling and i am just trying to debug as there are now no addresses being returned by getAddressesByAccount(req.user._id); so cannot see if the next part is working. The balance is collected and i can see the userID is right but the returned array of addresses is just []

Comment: I have attached my current code in progress with your changes to the bottom of my post above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12303/discussion-between-dan-abramov-and-medoix)